# Oracle on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: java, oracle, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to install oracle on snow leopard using these guidelines.
http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/
There is a step in the installation, where I have to change netca and dbca such that it runs in 32 bit mode. Can someone please tell me how to do it. I have pasted the exact step below

–Now you need to modify $ORACLE_HOME/jdk/bin/java script and change “…java -Xbootclasspath…” to “…java -d32 -Xbootclasspath…”--

Comment: should this be on superuser.com?

Comment: Previously the only supported OS X was the Server edition.  I could not tell from the download page if the client is supported today.  Not installing on a supported version is asking for trouble :(

Answer (score 2):

Break it down:

> Now you need to modify `$ORACLE_HOME/jdk/bin/java` script

OK, so there is a file in the directory that Oracle is installed in, which is *{path to Oracle installation}*/jdk/bin/java.  Open it up in your favorite text editor.

> ...and change “…java -Xbootclasspath…”

Search for the text `java -Xbootclasspath`...

> ...to “…java -d32 -Xbootclasspath…”

Now, you want to insert `-d32` in between `java` and `-Xbootclasspath`.  The `-d32` switch tells Java to run in 32-bit mode.

***Presto!***